# node express request handler in source code

Tags: node.js, express, requesthandler

I'm reading example [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) source code for my education.

Initializing a simple express application looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:3000`)
})
```

I want to understand what `app.listen` does in above code.

The source code of `app.listen` is defined in [express/lib/application.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.3/lib/application.js#L616-L619), as following:

```
var app = exports = module.exports = {};

// ...

app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this); // <-- why `this` ??
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

Typically, `http.createServer()` accepts a function as request handler. In this case, `this` was passed in. But `this` should refer to `app`, it's not a function, right?

Later I found out [app.handle](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.3/lib/application.js#L158-L175) was used as the request handler.

What is happening under the hood?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is an enhanced instance of the `app` prototype & it's being used as an options object for `http.createServer`. To trace this sort of answer, we need to fully understand Node's CommonJS module implementation, the JavaScript prototypical inheritance system & JavaScript function scope.

The answer lays behind these lines:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.3/lib/application.js#L38
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.3/lib/express.js#L43

`app` is a pointer to `module.exports`, which represents how that module gets interfaced with from other Node modules. That module is *only* ever used internally by Express in lib/express, where it gets mixed in with another JavaScript prototype before being instantiated. Once an instance, each of the `app` functions in lib/application share a `this` that can be used to reference every property value & function on its prototype.

So...

Because `http.createServer` accepts an options object as its 1st argument, `ServerResponse` & `IncomingMessage` will be used from `app`/`this` if available.

P.S. *do not* write code the way the Express team did it. You should never need to look through several modules to find the answer to a simple question like this. There are much simpler & team-friendly approaches to modularizing prototype mixins & default initializer options!

Comment: Thanks @james_womack, this helps a lot !